# Does this non-linear recurrence relation have a closed form solution?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

The recurrence relation is: $F(1,1)=1, F(n,k)=0$ if $k \leq 0$, $F(n,k)=0,$ if $k \geq 2n$ where
$$F(n+1,k) = F(n,k-2)F(n,k-1) + F(n,k).$$
I'm looking for a closed form solution for $F(n,n)$. Else, if not possible finding a generating function for it?

I have tried generating functions, but the first term is troublesome.

Comment: All terms are zero. Where is a nonzero term?

Comment: Woops, sorry about that, $F(1,1)=1$, edit made.

Comment: This is embarrassing. Fixed.